# Way of formatting Word so that a line occur at a given distance from page border?

Tags: ms-word

I don't know how to properly specify this question, but basically I would like to format a document like specified here : http://etd.lib.hku.hk/thesis-form/Theses%20Binding%20specification(ed%20January%202018)c.pdf

It's on the 3rd page of the PDF document. So I need to input a line at the exact distance from the top border, while another line occurs at some exact distance from the bottom.

Does MS Word give the flexibility to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow is a forum for helping people with programming questions, not with end-user issues. As such, your question is off-topic for this forum. Such questions are better asked in a forum such as MS Answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone points out this question is off-topic for this forum but just in case someone is here anyway: use **multiple text boxes** can be the solution.

A user can adjust a text box's relative position on a page and thus achieve the formatting needed.